# how can I solve vue3 module not found error - why is Vue looking for packages in my src directory?

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuejs3, vue-component, npm-install

I am using Vue3 and installing the vue3-google-login package,

this is the code I am using in main.js

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import vue3GoogleLogin from 'vue3-google-login';


const app = createApp(App)

app.use(vue3GoogleLogin, {
    clientId: 'id.apps.googleusercontent.com',
})
app.mount('#app')
```

and this is the app.vue

```
<script setup>

</script>

<template>
</template>
```

I am getting this error

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vue3-google-login' in
> 'prpojectdir\src'

vue cli version 5.0.8, vue3-google-login version 2.0.24, I have removed the node_modules + package.lock and ran `npm install` and tried to downgrade the google-login package and it did not help.

It seems like Vue is looking for this package in my project source, instead of in node modules, where it exists. How can I solve that?

Comment: It's specific to the package. As you can see, 2.0.24 is botched, it's empty. https://unpkg.com/browse/vue3-google-login@2.0.24/ Stick to the version that really has files in dist/ . If the problem persists, please, provide a way to reproduce, as this is something that needs to be examined

Comment: @EstusFlask same problem happened with 2.0.13 which was the latest I found with files in the dist